# How to calculate greenhouse effect for planet as well as for the atmosphere?

Tags: atmosphere, temperature, greenhouse-gases, sun, solar-terrestrial-physics

I recently found a calculation on how to calculate the greenhouse effect for Earth from another question here, but I couldn't make heads or tails of the calculations that were provided in one of the answers.

[How can we calculate the temperature of the atmosphere, including the greenhouse effect?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/12093/how-can-we-calculate-the-temperature-of-the-atmosphere-including-the-greenhouse)

Would it be possible for someone to explain the calculation structure and how to use it for exoplanets (worldbuilding exercise) like I'm five? I have no problem replicating the calculations once I know how to do it, but I just need to know what figures and units I need to use for the process.

At present, I know how to get the surface temperature for a planet without an atmosphere, so I just need help getting the calculation for a planet with an atmosphere.

Comment: Editing your question to include a link to the other question you mention might be useful to those who might be able to help you.

Comment: @Fred Added. Thanks for the reminder!