# Open-source earth model for climate change

Tags: climate, simulation

Is there popular open-source project on Earth Model for climate change assessment or global earth simulation ?

Best regards,
Adrien

Comment: See for instance [Isca](https://doi.org/10.5194/gmd-11-843-2018), which is open source.  I'm not sure how comprehensive it is: it looks as if it is aimed mostly at the rather-idealized level from casual reading, and without ocean models &c there's a lot missing.

Comment: If you find an open-source supercomputer to run it on, please stop by again and make a note of it here! ;-) You might also consider asking another question about the viability of demonstrating climate change on a personal computer versus a supercomputer facility.

Comment: There is a simplified climate model available from the University of Hamburg that is thought for educational purposes. It is called [Planet Simulator](https://www.mi.uni-hamburg.de/en/arbeitsgruppen/theoretische-meteorologie/modelle/plasim.html).

Comment: @daniel.neumann Can you add that as an answer?  I used that model in a climate physics PhD course and I recommend it.

Comment: @uhoh Planet Simulator that daniel.neumann mentioned gets some results on a PC, of course with nowhere near the resolution or realism of full-scale climate models, but still good as a toy model for educational purposes.

Comment: @gerrit that's cool! No, I mean hot! No, I mean... good to know. ;-) I really hope the question gets asked and answered.

Comment: @gerrit: Or would the Planet Simulator rather fit as an answer to the question [Simple Climate Models that Predict Climate Change](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/4874/5594)? If I find some calm time this week, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: @uhoh see my comment above; I know, comments shouldn't be used for chatting ...; sorry for that

Comment: @daniel.neumann It can be the answer to both...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked [PlanetSimulator](https://www.mi.uni-hamburg.de/en/arbeitsgruppen/theoretische-meteorologie/modelle/plasim.html) and I saw that it was mainly Fortran. Therefore I hoped a Python project or at least Java/C++ project that could be easily bind with Python. Nevertheless, thanks for the answers ;)

Comment: Accoring to your answer, you are looking for models written in a specific programming language. Please state so in the question and add further requirements of the model you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

## NOAA-GDFL model system for CMIP6

The *Geophysical Fluid Dynamics Laboratory* (GDFL) of the *National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration* (NOAA) uses an coupled open source modeling system for their contribution to CMIP6. CMIP6 is the *6th Coupled Model Intercomparion Project* (CMIP6) on which basis the [Sixth Assessment Report of the IPCC](https://www.ipcc.ch/assessment-report/ar6/) (the upcoming report) will be partly based on.

The model system of the GDFL consists of several components that have to be compiled invidually and couled to each other. The ocean is represented by the [Modular Ocean Model v6 (MOM)](https://github.com/NOAA-GFDL/MOM6) and the atmosphere is represented by their [Atmosphere Model v4.5 (AM)](https://github.com/NOAA-GFDL/AM4). Both models are open source. But, I am not sure under which licence they are published. There are further components needed for the proper climate model system setup. Have a look in [this json file](https://github.com/WCRP-CMIP/CMIP6_CVs/blob/master/CMIP6_experiment_id.json) for possible combinations.

## Educational climate model: Planet Simulator

This text section was already posted by me as an [answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/19296/5594) to the question [Simple Climate Models that Predict Climate Change](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/4874/5594).

The Meteorological Institute of the University of Hamburg, Germany, provides and simple model called [**"Planet Simulator" (PlaSim)**](https://www.mi.uni-hamburg.de/en/arbeitsgruppen/theoretische-meteorologie/modelle/plasim.html).

The Planet Simulator is mainly made for educational purposes and runs on personal computers. However, it is also parallalized and can be run on HPC clusters. There exists an [Documentation](https://www.mi.uni-hamburg.de/en/arbeitsgruppen/theoretische-meteorologie/modelle/sources/psusersguide.pdf) and the source code is said to be well commented. The whole source code is open source. The programming language is Fortran. One should be able to compile it with `gfortran` under Linux.

The Planet Simulator offers a GUI (after compiling successfully) to set up da model simulation and run it. There is code for postprocessing included. Thus, there is not need for additional postprocessing software. If you write out the output as `netCDF`, which is the quasi-standard output format of climate models, it might be practical to install [`ncview`](http://meteora.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncview_home_page.html) or [`Panoply`](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/) because these are common netCDF viewers with which you can look directly into the output files.